# Google sheets: chart with steps of constant height change, variable width

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to draw a chart in Google Sheets to represent the position of a stepper motor. As the motor speeds up, it steps more quickly. But in this case, it can only ever move one step at a time. So if I want to draw a graph of its position,  when it's accelerating, the chart would look like a staircase, where each step is of the same height, but the distance between steps decreases (so the staircase gets steeper as it climbs.

I've come close to doing this:

[image]

Except the steps shown are not what I want; they are of constant width and varying height. I need the reverse. The data points I provided don't lend themselves to the graph I want; they just demonstrate the kind of curve I want.

How might I tabulate data and create a chart to give the kind of steps I need? For example, I might have a column which contains individual step widths,  and another with step height (which would always be 1.) But then how to make that into a chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Stepped area chart* does not support variable width of steps. But you can use the ordinary *area chart* like this:

[image: area chart]

The data provided to this chart was as follows. The first column was marked for "use as labels" when inserting the chart.

```
0.00    0
1.00    0
1.00    1
1.41    1
1.41    2
1.73    2
1.73    3
2.00    3
2.00    4
2.24    4
2.24    5
2.45    5
2.45    6
2.65    6
2.65    7
2.83    7
```

The idea is that each x value is repeated twice, and each y value is repeated twice, but they are half-step out of sync with each other. So every time we move down the rows, exactly one of two coordinates changes: x (horizontal segment) or y (vertical segment).

For the record, the formulas were `=sqrt(floor(row()/2))` and `=floor((row()-1)/2)` and the chart options were

[image: options]